# Check if Rails association created in past x days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, cron

I'm trying to create a `CRON` job to monitor the activity status of a `user` on my platform.

It's supposed to check if the user has purchased something or messaged someone, and send an email if not. My method for the same is:

```
def self.create_new_user_reminders
  @new_users = User.where({ banned: false, admin: false })

  @new_users = @new_users.reject { |u| u.client.try(:purchases).any? or  u.client.try(:conversations).any? }

  @new_users.each do |nu|
    SalesMailer.delay.signup_no_engagement(nu)
  end
end
```

Now I want to extend this to include a condition which would send an email if a client hasn't purchased something or messaged someone in the past 14 days.

`Client` is related to `Purchases` and `Conversations` as a `has_many` association.

One way I can think of doing this is buy creating nested loops and reject specific `purchases` and `messages` but this would be really inefficient.

What's a good way of implementing this on Rails?

Comment: What is a client? Is it an attribute on User or a method defined in the User model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `created_at` to check if the user has purchased something or messaged someone

```
@new_users = @new_users.reject { |u| u.client.try(:purchases).where('created_at > ?', 14.days.ago).any? or  u.client.try(:conversations).where('created_at > ?', 14.days.ago).any? }
```